# Row Selection changes when I add a dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I click on any one row and click the delete link the confirmation dialog box appears but once I click on the dialog box , the row selection changes.The selected is not getting deleted but some other row gets deleted.Kindly Help to fix it.

```
<p:column headerText="Delete" width="50" style="text-align:center">
            <p:commandLink id="showDialogButton"
                update=":studyPlanEditForm:display" onclick="cdDialog.show()"
                value="delete">
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:dialog widgetVar="cdDialog" appendToBody="true"
                header="Are you sure to delete this substudyplan?">
                <p:panel>
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" process=":studyPlanEditForm:display" 
                    action="#{editBean.deleteSubStudyPlan(selectedRow)}"
                    onclick="cdDialog.hide();"
                    update=":studyPlanEditForm"/>
                <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="cdDialog.hide();"
                     type="button"/>
                </p:panel>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialog has to be outside the table. Also, in the delete button you are updating component ":studyPlanEditForm:display". I don't see that component in the snippet. The panel inside the dialog should have id="display", because the dialog needs to be updated.

You can see a working example of a similar use casi in primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf). You only have to replace the dialog that shows content for the confirm message, and add a button that deleted the row. The managed bean already has a reference to the selected row.

This is how the delete button would look like

```
<p:column headerText="Delete" width="50" style="text-align:center">
    <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton"
             update=":studyPlanEditForm:display" onclick="cdDialog.show()"
             value="delete">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{selectedRow}" target="#{bean.selectedRow}" />
      </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

And this is the dialog (has to be outside table):

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="cdDialog" appendToBody="true"
          header="Are you sure to delete this substudyplan?">
    <p:panel id="display">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" process="@this" 
                action="#{editBean.deleteSubStudyPlan}"
                onclick="cdDialog.hide();"
                update=":studyPlanEditForm"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="cdDialog.hide();"
                 type="button"/>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

So the managed bean has an attribute called `selectedRow` and at the time method deleteSubStudyPlan is invoked, this attribute contains the entity that belongs to the selected row in the table.

Comment: Hi Sorry for being late The problem is the variable selectedRow is inside the dataTable; So I can not use action="#{editBean.deleteSubStudyPlan(selectedRow)}" Please Help.

Comment: @PraveenV I edited answer. didn't you look at the primefaces showcase?